# Demonstrate how to calculate R1, R2, R3, R4 for VOUT of 3 volts

Tags: voltage, transistors, resistors, bjt, voltage-divider

[image]

can someone help me with this?

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Well, there's no unique answer. Why don't you start by assuming, say, R3 = 1K and tell us how far that takes you.

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. We expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: im not a college student, im trying to educate myself think of this as a hobby but if I'm being honest I need guidance it's hard to find any good resources without having to put in a lot of money I don't have. its fine fine tho, thanks for the help

Comment: @Dave You say you don't know where to start. If that's really correct then you are probably not yet ready to wade into the deeper end of the pool. Do you know about KVL or KCL? Can you describe how to tell if a BJT is in *active* mode and what that means to a design?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: If you are starting learning, you do NOT start with the hard problems, but the basics.  Choose another problem where resistors are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to start:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVjQv0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First off, I've separated out and labeled the \$+10\:\text{V}\$ points and the ground points. This removes the **unimportant** wires, which tend to add confusion more than they help. (They are important if you are wiring this up. But they are NOT important when you are trying to understand it.)

I've provided some additional annotations. Some are directly from the problem and some are just my own "suggestion" for you to consider.

But take note that the voltage drops across each parts in series like this must sum to the total power supply value. This applies to the section shown on the left and it applies also to the section on the right.

One thing to note here is that if there is \$2\:\text{V}\$ across an NPN BJT's collector-emitter leads as shown, then the BJT is in *active* mode (assuming the base is about a diode drop above \$V_{_\text{E}}\$.) This means you can expect to see \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx I_{_\text{E}}\$ and that the base current will be very low, about \$\frac1{\beta}I_{_\text{C}}\$, which is almost *negligible*.

As a clue to start, if \$I_{_\text{C}}\approx I_{_\text{E}}\$ then about the same current is in \$R_3\$ as is in \$R_4\$. So if you take my suggestion in the diagram, you should be able to see why you also should expect that \$R_3\approx 7\cdot R_4\$. And this means you've already got a useful ratio to use in the design process.

There are a number of other details. But this is a start. I'd like to see what else you can add to what I've already given as a starting point.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is to say that there must be 7V across R3 in order to have Vout = 3V. Therefore what current (Ic) is flowing through it? Essentially the same current flows through R4 so what voltage is there across R4? Hence what is Vb? (0.7V > Ve). You can now calculate the ratio of R1 to R2 in order to achieve this.

Comment: @PeterJennings I was being careful about what I know and what I have to allow that the OP doesn't know. One of those things I worried about is the ability of the OP to work out what *stiff* means for a base voltage divider pair. I decided NOT to assume that the OP is aware of the idea and/or why it is an idea, at all. So I stayed clear of it, for now.

Comment: @jonk Thanks this helped a lot